# Electricity bills to bitcoin earned

Tags: mining-profitability, energy-consumption

Im running an acer aspire 5 with an Intel i5 10th gen CPU with 16 gigs of memory. With only crypto tab open and mining Bitcoin, how much electricity is consumed if I run it for a week straight?

I am only using PC mine will I earn more bitcoin than one wall outlet electricity cost per week?

Comment: You will consume some amount of electricity, and most certainly get zero bitcoin in return.

Answer (score 0):

First off as chytrik has pointed out were are in the age of ASIC dominance on Bitcoin which means you can not expect ANY CPU to compete practically especially not profitably.

Secondly mining revenue is complicated, if you actually do want to participate with ASIC mining a good website to look at is https://whattomine.com specifically https://whattomine.com/miners for the ASICS.

This website gives you **ESTIMATES** of mining profit across all types of hardware, algorithms, coins. But keep in mind these are estimates taken from data that is constantly changing, it is not meant to be long term investment advice by any means.

If we look at the most profitable ASIC on this site right now it is https://whattomine.com/miners/223-bitmain-antminer-s19-xp-hydro?cost=0.1&cost_currency=USD you will see that it is profiting ~$5 a day not counting nice hash. This is calculated to be on top of power which is one reason I really like this site for estimates. Otherwise the older the ASIC you get the less likely it will pay off power immediately, but IMO given the long term of Bitcoin price action even inefficient ASICs should do OK given you don't over-extend your risk tolerance on them.